# Specialized version of the cross correlation function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, statistics

I am writing a specialized version of the cross correlation function as used in neuroscience. The function below is supposed to take a time series `data` and ask how many of its values fall in specified bins. My function `xcorr` works but is horrifically slow even. A test data set with 1000 points (and so 0.5*(1000*999) intervals) distributed over 400 bins takes almost ten minutes.

**Bottleneck**

The bottleneck is in the line `counts = array([sum ...`. I assume it is there because each iteration of the `foreach` loop searches through the entire vector `diffs`, which is of length `len(first)**2`.

```
def xcorr(first,second,dt=0.001,window=0.2,savename=None):
    length = min(len(first),len(second))
    diffs = array([first[i]-second[j] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(length)])
    bins = arange(-(int(window/dt)),int(window/dt))
    counts = array[sum((diffs>((i-.5)*dt)) & (diffs<((i+.5)*dt))) for i in bins]
    counts -= len(first)**2*dt/float(max(first[-1],second[-1])) #Normalization
    if savename:
        cPickle.dump((bins*dt,counts),open(savename,'wb'))
    return (bins,counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crack at my own question that uses built-in functions from `NumPy`

**Update**

The function chain `bincount(digitize(data,bins))` is equivalent to `histogram`, which allows for a more succinct expression.

```
 def xcorr(first,second,dt=0.001,window=0.2,savename=None):
      length = min(len(first),len(second))
      diffs = array([first[i]-second[j] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(length)])
      counts,edges = histogram(diffs,bins=arange(-window,window,dt))
      counts -= length**2*dt/float(first[length])
      if savename:
           cPickle.dump((counts,edges[:-1]),open(savename,'wb'))
      return (counts,edges[:-1])
```

The indexing in the `return` statement comes because I want to ignore the edge bins.

Answer (score 0):

Going to try to help you do this in a faster fashion rather than write the code for you entirely:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now you can easily do your diffs without those slow loops - note my comments should help but basically you are taking advantage of Pandas very fast and simple calculation on the time series; .shift(1) if 1st row is the OLDEST date (example is for the NEWEST date in 1st row .shift(-1)).  Likewise you can shift(2) if the calculation is 2 rows away.  Modify to use your algorithm:

```
diffs = (data[0:] - data[0:].shift(-1))/data[0:]
```

Okay back to your bottleneck issue.  Can you tell in your question after your NumPy modification which line is slow?  Just counting bins?